# For loop is not working properly-its skipping sometimes

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a product called customized gift box with different sizes like 5,9,12 etc.

When the users select items to the gift box and add to cart, I am fetching those chocolate names too with the Quantity of the chocolate.

In the code below, I have written if the product name includes customized then fetch the related chocolate using session in a for loop.

And the For loop is working properly but, sometimes it doesn't.

How can this be resolved?

```
<?php 
if(stristr($this->getProductUrl(),"customized")){
?>
<div>
<?php
echo "<br/>";

$itid = $_item->getId();
echo $itid;
$strrep = str_replace(' ','_',$this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()));
for($k=1;$k<=sizeof($_SESSION[$strrep."item".$itid]);$k++){
  if($_SESSION[$strrep."item".$itid][$k]!=""){
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size='1px'>".$_SESSION[$strrep."qty".$itid][$k]." x ".$_SESSION[$strrep."item".$itid][$k]."</font><br/>";
  }
}
?>

</div>
```

Comment: In your `for` loop `if` condition sometimes `true`, sometimes `false`

Comment: it sounds like you are missing something sometimes :) it could be the SESSION variable. make sure that `$_SESSION[$strrep."item".$itid]` has a value in it before your `for`loop.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen  I have checked it.The problem is with session.If the product has 10 sub products the session is displaying only 3 to 4 products and some times it displays properly..

Comment: Then I guess you should double check the code piece where you persist those product objects into your session. You might be missing something. And I feel like I need make a suggestion to about the usage of session, just use it for session purposes, such as authentication, not for business logic operations, use get or post variables instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop starts with 1 and finishes with the `sizeof`'s element. Array indices are zero based in PHP so you should do

```
for ($k=0;$k<count($_SESSION[$strrep."item".$itid]);$k++){
  ...
}
```

instead. I also replaced `sizeof()` by `count()` but that is a matter of preference ...

Comment: Have used count() instead of sizeof() but still i didn't get the output properly

Comment: have you started your loop from `$k=0` and ended it with  `i < count(...)` (*not* `<=`)?  .. And, of course, as Alexander Larikov already said: you only echo when the condition `if($_SESSION[$strrep."item".$itid][$k]!="")` is met, and that is not necessarily the case for all values of `$k`.